# WhatsApp prompting me to update my browser

Tags: google-chrome, whatsapp

I am trying to access WhatsApp Web and I get the following message:

> WhatsApp Web works for Google Chrome 36+
>   To start using WhatsApp Web, update Chrome or use Mozilla Firefox, Safari, or Opera.

I run Chrome version 43+ so this makes no sense.

What seems to be the error?

Comment: Happens to me so often on so very many sites, I don't let it bother me any more. Some websites even complain that they can only work properly with browsers running under Windows as opposed to Linux. If I really need to visit such a site, I just change my useragent string.

Comment: They are probably using a technique to detect your browser version that can break at even slightest errors in data. Would be looking at their source code though to see what actually does it.

Comment: It started happening again. I resolved using WhatsApp Web in an incognito Chrome window. It works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After speaking with WhatsApp support the answer is that some extensions make the application think it's a another version of Chrome. It was indeed the answer. In my particular case it happened to be an extension called "Smooth Scroll".

Comment: Interesting,
I had the same problem- then disabled 2 extensions: HD for YouTube and Chrome for Kindle Now I was able to access whatsapp via Chrome.
then reenabled both extensions And I was still able to access whatsapp

Comment: For me, the extension that I had to disable was "FirePHP4Chrome". I guess they don't want us to be sneaking down the ajax calls :D

Comment: It happened to me today, and i have not installed any new extension in a really long time. so i am wondering if that's the issue

Comment: I tried disabling all extensions, ad blockers, miners blockers, etc. but no luck. The only way I got it working is in an incognito windows.

Answer (score 6):

Whatever algorithm they're using to detect your browser is faulty. Unless and until they fix it, you should follow their advice and use a different browser.